# CS5001 for test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I'm currently working on a .net core 5.0 console app
I have lately reinstalled my visual studio app when changing computer, my working project is now facing some issues.
The testprojects don't have any main method anymore.
this is the error being returned by Visual Studio

```bash
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point database-serviceTests   C:\...\myProject\database-serviceTests\CSC  1   Active
```

I've seen online that those methods are being auto generated by the app, but I find nowhere where to regenerate them.
Is there another way than recreating new test projects and moving all the contents inside?
thank you

I have tried to clean, build, rebuild, changed the "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version (using 17.4.0 right now). Only changing .Net.Test.sdk version has been a working workaround for this, but this will not pass for later reviews.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need a main method? How are you trying to execute the tests, and what's preventing you from doing it? Are you getting a specific error message? Please describe your situation in proper detail.

Comment: Yep, forgot to copy the error code in my question, my bad

To make it clearer, I'm looking after a way for my testproject to regenerate the "auto-generated" code it requires to run, if this exists in visual studio or not

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a `Main` method in a test project.  The projects are usually executed by Visual Studio's test runner.  How are you executing it?

Comment: There are `Main()` methods (entry points) for desktop or console apps but looking for one for test projects is odd to me.

Comment: This is a [classic XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You're asking about your proposed solution (adding a main method to a test project) rather than adequately describing the goal: execute the tests. If you run it from VS, you use the Test Explorer. If you run it from the command line, you use [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test).

Comment: Me neither, I haven't defined `Main` , I'm just using Visual Studio's test explorer to run them

From what I've learned, when creating a test project, the backend auto generates a Main method that will run the unit tests, for the test explorer or something, I don't know

Comment: Are you saying that when you use Visual Studio's test explorer to run the tests, you're getting that error message? What specific actions are you taking in order to execute the tests?

Comment: When running the tests from my test explorer, during app build , it returns a cs5001 for all my test projects,

Comment: Tests don't have "Main" methods. The test runner, in this case Visual Studio, detects and runs all test methods

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, but my test project still asks for one at build

Comment: Test projects are class libraries so they never ask for a `Main`. I suspect a `Console` project was created instead of an MS Test project by mistake

Comment: That's what I also thought, but Visual Studio detects it as an `MS Test Project` , when checking the test project properties, in Application/General/OutputType it says `Console Application` , but I cannot change it though

Comment: Why can't you change it? Anything stopping you from editing the .csproj file directly to change it? Or creating a brand new test project so that it properly creates it as a class library instead of a console application?

Comment: I'm not allowed to recreate other test projects, how could I edit this in the .csproje file? it's weird because it's not happening on my coworkers computer. Might have a look and reinstall my visual studio completely.

Comment: A .csproj file is just a text file. Use any text editor you like to edit it. Compare that to a brand new unit test project to see what it should look like.

Comment: I just remade a test project (it had the 1 after in the name) and compared the .csproj files, The only difference was a "isTestProject" property, I added and set it to true.
But anything has changed ...

Comment: @mason I'll try completely reinstalling my IDE as this is only happening on my current computer and will come back afterwards, this could be app related

Comment: So I just reinstalled completely my IDE, but the error keeps weirdly happening.
Cloned other asp.net repos from my work git repositoriesn but this doesnt seem like it's helping though...

Comment: This error does not happen on other projects.
I managed to find a workaround by switching package versions, cleaning and rebuilding the app with VS' tools:
1. `Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK` went from 17.4.0 to 16.7.1 
2. `MSTest.TestAdapter` went from 3.0.0 to 2.1.1
3. `MSTest.TestFramework` went from 3.0.0 to 2.1.1

Since then, all my errors have disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference from Elie De Tavernier:

The solution can be found by switching package versions, cleaning and rebuilding the application using VS tools:

1. Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK changed from 17.4.0 to 16.7.1
2. MSTest.TestAdapter changed from 3.0.0 to 2.1.1
3. MSTest.TestFramework from 3.0.0 to 2.1.1